# Using Jquery .load() with only a callback specified not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a div with a video that I am changing by modifying its src attribute on event and then loading the div to play the video. This all works fine and well.

html

```
<div id="screen">
    <video autoplay loop>
        <source id="vid_source" src=""  type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

jquery

```
if (index == 3) {
    vidSrc = "video.mp4";
    $("#vid_source").attr("src", vidSrc);
    $("video").load();
    $("#screen").fadeIn();
}
```

What I want to do is instead add the `$("#screen").fadeIn();` to the callback of the load function. When I update the code to do this:

```
$("video").load(function() {
    $("#screen").fadeIn();
});
```

The callback is not firing for some reason, although the source attribute is updated properly. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `load(fn)` handler *before* you change the `src` attribute?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan also not working.

Comment: @pwneth have you tried firing an alert for example ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek yes, the callback is not firing at all. the load function is working with no parameters, but not with the callback.

Comment: @pwneth can provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> Caveats of the load event when used with images ( **same applies to videos** )
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the
  same src as  before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree   Can cease to fire
- for images that already live in the browser's cache

**Solution:**

I would suggest trying this :

```
$("video").on("load",function() {
    $("#screen").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: is there a way to wait until the video is actually loaded though, to do the fadein? Currently this is still triggering the fadeIn at the same time as load, not after it is finished

Comment: @pwneth yes , but you need to define your video as an object , then use native .onload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65827/discussion-between-pwneth-and-prollygeek).

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to your video:

```
$("video").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
  $("#screen").fadeIn();
});
```

[workind demo](http://codepen.io/alfredbez/pen/ogXOyE)

A complete list of mediaevents: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#mediaevents

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.